# Scala Cats: How do I convert a List[ValidatedNel[E, A]] to Ior[NonEmptyList[E], List[A]]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I tried:

```
def convert[E, A](in: List[ValidatedNel[E, A]]): Ior[NonEmptyList[E], List[A]] =
    in.separate
```

I get:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter G: cats.Bifoldable[cats.data.ValidatedNel]
[error]     in.separate
```

I then tried something like this:

```
  def convert[E, A](in: List[ValidatedNel[E, A]]): Ior[NonEmptyList[E], List[A]] =
    in.traverse(_.toIor)
```

Now I got:

```
 could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.Applicative[G]
[error]     in.traverse(_.toIor)
```

Comment: Should you enable partial unification to let `scalac` infer `G`?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Toxaris mentioned, `-Ypartial-unification` needed to be toggled on